# golang "goinstall" command missing

Tags: go

I just installed golang on my machine. It appears that the way to install third party libraries is via the "goinstall" command, however this did not appear to install as part of the OSX package installer.

Am I missing something here?

Carl

Comment: `goinstall` was replaced by `go get` REF https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downloading and installing packages and dependencies is normally done using **[`go get`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)**

```
go get github.com/user/package
```

Or **[`go install`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)** when compiling and installing third party packages:

```
go install github.com/user/tool
```

Answer (score 2):

You may reference the old tutorial or book. Read these.

- http://golang.org/doc/code.html (must read)
- http://golang.org/cmd/
- http://golang.org/cmd/go/

goinstall is replaced by `go install`, I often use `go get -u` to get updated source.

Another tip is `go get -d` in your *.go source directory, then, it will get related packages automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You use go get like:

```
go get http://github.com/test
```

This downloads the package to your
GitHub folder into your workspace.

```
Go install
```

Installs an exe file inside your bin folder.